# How would I make the box-shadow of my div fade in on hover (and out when not hovering over it)?

Tags: css, animation, hover

I am just playing around with animations. I have a div with three box-shadows, which I want to fade in when the div is hovered on, one after the other, starting with the one closest to the div. I also want the reverse to happen when someone stops hovering on the div. Any idea how to achieve this?

```css
#div2 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px blueviolet inset, -15px -15px 10px blueviolet inset;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  transition: box-shadow 2s ease;
}

#div2:hover {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px darkblue, 10px 10px 3px blue, 15px 15px 5px lightblue, 15px 15px 10px blueviolet inset, -15px -15px 10px blueviolet inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are animating multiple `box-shadow`, make sure the amount of the shadows matches. So the browser would know which `box-shadow` is which.

For instance, I just copied the `box-shadow` from `:hover`, and make some of them transparent with a distance of `0px`:

```css
#div2 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  box-shadow: 
    0px 0px 1px transparent, 
    0px 0px 3px transparent, 
    0px 0px 5px transparent, 
    15px 15px 10px blueviolet inset, 
    -15px -15px 10px blueviolet inset;
    
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  transition: box-shadow 2s ease;
}

#div2:hover {
  box-shadow: 
    5px 5px 1px darkblue, 
    10px 10px 3px blue, 
    15px 15px 5px lightblue, 
    15px 15px 10px blueviolet inset, 
    -15px -15px 10px blueviolet inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```